# Finding name attributes inside a tag using php

Tags: php, html

i want to find the name attribute with in a tag in a form using php4 . Does any one help me how it find..

eg

```
<input type="text" name="txt_name" value="" >
```

I want to know name of all the fields

Comment: Do you want to do this on form-submission, form-creation or via cURL or SOAP?

Answer (score 1):

You need a library/code which implements an HTML DOM, look at [these SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+html+dom) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple html dom as mentioned by Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams

Add it in your code like this
    require_once('Simple_html_dom.php');

To use it I initialized it using this line

```
$html = new Simple_html_dom();
```

Load a page or link using the line

```
$html->load_file('http://www.yourste.com/yourpage.php');
```

to parse and find this element

```
$e = $html->find("input", 0);
```

the echo the value of attribute name

```
echo $value = $e->name
```

Answer (score 0):

When you submit a form, a url is send to the server in the form "name=value&name1=value1" etc. Here the "name" stands for the attribute "name" of an html element. So If you are using the $_GET or a $_POST then you can get the form item names in an array as follows

```
$names=array();
foreach($_GET as $key => $value)
{
  $names[] = $key;
}
print_r($names);
```